# Run Time Error 1004 - Application defined or object defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting this error on the last line of this code

```
Set Cumulative = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cumulative")

RefWeek = Cumulative.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row - 6
Cells(RefWeek, 1).Select
Cumulative.Range(Cells(RefWeek, 1), Cells(RefWeek + 6, 16)).Copy
```

Can anyone help please? :/

(There's more code in this but i'm getting the error on this part. If you need me to add the rest please ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UNTESTED:***

```
Set Cumulative = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cumulative")
With Cumulative
     RefWeek = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row - 6
     Range(.Cells(RefWeek, 1), .Cells(RefWeek + 6, 16)).Copy
End With
```

Note I dropped the `Select` which requires the proper worksheet to be `Select`ed first.

Comment: @TimWilliams Which one ?

Comment: @TimWilliams Dot's something I do too often. *(vbg)*

Comment: Thanks @Gary'sStudent that worked! :) (was missing the sheet reference before Cells)

Comment: Second to last line before Range